# Use service acount default credentials in Google Bigquery command line tool

Tags: google-bigquery, credentials, service-accounts, command-line-tool

I want to use service account with default credentials in bq command.
How can I make the following command read the key-file from environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:

```
gcloud auth active-service-account
```

Comment: Have you tried `gcloud auth active-service-account --key-file $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`?

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks

Comment: The command that worked for me was
`gcloud auth login --cred-file $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`